Are you liable for damages while protecting someone else from damage?
Let's say Reuven is attempting (or has already begun) to damage Shimon (or Shimon's belongings) and Levi shows up to defend Shimon from Reuven. In successfully warding off Reuven, Levi also ends up damaging Shimon (or Shimon's stuff). Who, if anyone, is liable for Levi's damages?

To the point that Shimon would agree to act himself. But we follow dinah demalhutah dinah (local customs) - whatever the court sees fit.

The relevant halachah is in Shulchan Aruch, Choshen Mishpat 380:3 (ultimately from the Gemara, Bava Kamma 117b):

ואחד שרדף אחר הרודף להציל את הנרדף ושבר כלים בין של רודף בין של כל אדם פטור כדי שלא יבואו מלימנע מלהציל את הנרדף
If one [Levi, in your example] pursues a would-be assailant [Reuven] to save the potential victim [Shimon], and he breaks utensils - whether they belong to the assailant or to anyone else - he is exempt [from payment], so that people don't hesitate to save a would-be victim.

The Business Halacha Institute has an article with some further relevant details (see the section of that page titled "Emergency!"), in particular whether this exemption also applies to something that Levi borrows for the purpose (e.g., Levi borrows a weapon to fight off Reuven, and damages it in the process).

thanks for this answer, I believe there was a misunderstanding of my question which was not regarding a life-threatening situation
